# Can't find Barracuda package in Unity Registry

Tags: unity-game-engine, package, barracuda

Following the instructions [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@1.0/manual/Installing.html) in the "Unity Package Manager" section, I'm unable to find the Barracuda package in the Unity Registry. Could someone shed some light on how Barracuda package is meant to be installed? Thanks!

[image]

I do have Preview Packages enabled, as you can see some preview packages listed in the Unity Registry in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/visibility-changes-for-preview-packages-in-2020-1.910880/), Unity versions since 2020 not only hide preview packages by default but for some, they are completely unsearchable and must be manually fetched. For Barracuda:

1. Open Package Manager
2. Click the plus sign in top left corner > Add package from Git URL...

[image]

3. Input `com.unity.barracuda` into the text field